# Where can I get electrical plans for my new house?

Tags: building-regulations

I'm planning a few upgrades to the wiring in my condo that will require filing plans with the city.  It would make my life a lot easier if I had the existing electrical plans (and probably other systems, too).  The condo is new construction and I bought it from the builder.

Is it customary for the builder to provide copies of the plans if requested?

Comment: In the UK you can view plans at the building-reg if they have been submited in the past, but not copy them.  It may be your home, but the plans are considered to be copy-right of the person that submited them!

Comment: I talked to the city building department and they said I could come view the plans... when the whole tract is completed.  I will see if I can get them directly from the builder in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Walker none of the plans I have ever seen for UK domestic building work have had any real information on the wiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's common in most places for the local government (town/city hall) to have the plans on file. Keep in mind though that sometimes work is done without plans or permits, so use the plans as a guide not an exact map.

*Comment converted to answer*

Comment: It's also possible that the plans were not followed exactly - for example, a light circuit to be attached to the nearest outlet because the run was shorter/easier.

Answer (score 1):

On the west coast of Canada (at least) it is rare for there to exist either planned or as-built plans for electrical (, plumbing, or HVAC) for residential homes (whether single or multi-dwelling buildings).

Floorplans, elevation drawings, and lot plans are required by most municipalities to be submitted to the public record.